# PHP Algorithm to Sort Exponential Numbers (a^b)

Tags: php, sorting, exponent

I am generating random numbers in the format `a^b` to try and sort them, these are usually numbers between 100 and 10,000 but have simplified it to 1 and 10 for testing purposes.

```
$numbers = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    // $a = $faker->numberBetween(100, 10000);
    // $b = $faker->numberBetween(100, 10000);

    $a = $faker->numberBetween(1, 10);
    $b = $faker->numberBetween(1, 10);

    $numbers[] = [$a, $b];
}

function powerSort($numbers) {
    usort($numbers, function ($a, $b) {
        // base numbers are the array key and exponents the value
        // first check if the exponent is larger
        list($baseA, $exponentA) = $a;
        list($baseB, $exponentB) = $b;

        if ($exponentA > $exponentB) {
            return 1;
        } else if ($exponentB > $exponentA) {
            return -1;
        } elseif ($exponentA === $exponentB) {
            // compare base numbers
            if ($baseA > $baseB) {
                return 1;
            } elseif ($baseB > $baseA) {
                return -1;
            }
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    });
}
```

the problem is this is clearly wrong:

```
+----------+
| Unsorted |
+----------+
| 10^2     |
| 2^2      |
| 2^1      |
| 10^8     |
| 2^8      |
| 5^3      |
| 9^4      |
| 3^7      |
| 3^9      |
| 1^8      |
+----------+

+--------+
| Sorted |
+--------+
| 2^1    |
| 2^2    |
| 10^2   |
| 5^3    |
| 9^4    |
| 3^7    |
| 1^8    |
| 2^8    |
| 10^8   |
| 3^9    |
+--------+
```

I believe for it to work, the numbers would need to be expressed to the same power, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: explode the string on '^' and consider the parts accordig to your sorting logic.

Comment: One problem is as the numbers get bigger the chances of being able to compare them becomes more difficult.  As you say, you need to have them in some common form, which can be done using `return pow($baseA, $exponentA) <=> pow($baseB, $exponentB);` to just evaluate the actual number.

Comment: thanks Nigel, yeah, I was thinking of something similar originally, but was getting `INF` when trying to display the numbers, but the sorting itself seems to work fine - keep forgetting about the spaceship operator! Just wondering if there's a better way to do it in order to avoid calculating so many large numbers.